# IONIC 3 - AdMob Free not Working even If isTesting is set true

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, admob, cordova-admob

I am trying from last 3 days to run Google AdMob in Ionic 3 application. 
Steps I followed:

**1.** Created Ionic 3 App added AdMob Free.

**2.** To check if my AdMob account stopped ads, create a native android sample app of that banner ads started showing real-time. Real Ads, not Test.

**3.** Create a new Ionic 3 sample app but still no success.

Anyone facing similar issue?? please help Let me know if anything left which I forgot to follow.

I followed a tutorial given [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-3-how-to-integrate-google-admob-advertisements/#more-1055)

Here is my code:

Installed these packages:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save
npm install @ionic-native/admob-free --save
```

**app.module.ts**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

    import { AdMobFree } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';



    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        AdMobFree,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**home.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AdMobFree, AdMobFreeBannerConfig, AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig, AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig } from '@ionic-native/admob-free';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public admobFree: AdMobFree) {

      }

      showBannerAd() {

          let bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
              isTesting: true, // Remove in production
              autoShow: true//,
              //id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
          };
          this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

          this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
              alert("bannerConfig");
          }).catch(e => alert(e));
      }



      showInterstitialAds(){
          let interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
              isTesting: true, // Remove in production
              autoShow: true//,
              //id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
          };
          this.admobFree.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);
          this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare().then(() => {
            alert("interstitialConfig");
          }).catch(e => alert(e));
      }

      showRewardVideoAds(){
          let RewardVideoConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
              isTesting: true, // Remove in production
              autoShow: true//,
              //id: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"
          };
          this.admobFree.rewardVideo.config(RewardVideoConfig);
          this.admobFree.rewardVideo.prepare().then(() => {
            alert("RewardVideoConfig");
          }).catch(e => alert(e));
      }


    }
```

**home.html**

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
          Ionic Blank
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
      The world is your oyster.
      <p>
        If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
      </p>

      <button ion-button (click)="showBannerAd()">showBannerAd</button>
      <button ion-button (click)="showInterstitialAds()">showInterstitialAds</button>
      <button ion-button (click)="showRewardVideoAds()">showRewardVideoAds</button>
    </ion-content>
```

**UPDATE: Finally!! Ads are showing. may be it takes 2-3 days.** :)

Comment: Do you get an error when you run it on a device ?

Comment: cordova_not_available error gets thrown by .catch(e => alert(e)); even if isTesting: true in config.

Any solution guys?

Answer (score 1):

just try this in the command line(put your app Id between ""):

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="**YOUR_APP_ID**"

example :

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --save --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="ca-app-pub-90001987983570300~8789081597"

Comment: done but getting cordova_not_available error gets thrown by .catch(e => alert(e));

Answer (score 0):

make sure to test it in emulator only, else you will get plugin not installed error.